# RewriteRule to another url isn't working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii, url-rewriting

I want the root url to redirect to other page, and any other url stays at my page. This is my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/test/ [L,R=301]
```

End when I enter

```
http://mypage.com/any_parameter
```

Everythings is ok, I hit my http://mypage.com/any_parameter

But when I enter

```
http://mypage.com/
```

it redirects me to http://www.example.com/, not http://www.example.com/test/

Could you please tell me what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change order of your rules and then make sure you clear your browser cache:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/test/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

If that still doesn't work then open Firebug's Net tab and then visit `http://mypage.com/` to see what redirects you're getting.